# How do I allocate space to call GetInterfaceInfo using the windows crate?

Tags: windows, api, rust, struct, buffer

I'm trying to fetch information regarding the network interfaces available on the system via [`GetInterfaceInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getinterfaceinfo) using Microsoft's [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate. This requires me to do some unsafe operations, and I get it to work for one interface, but not two:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use windows::{
        core::*, Data::Xml::Dom::*, Win32::Foundation::*, Win32::NetworkManagement::IpHelper::*,
        Win32::System::Threading::*, Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*,
    };

    #[test]
    fn main() {
        unsafe {
            let mut dw_out_buf_len: u32 = 0;

            let mut dw_ret_val =
                GetInterfaceInfo(std::ptr::null_mut(), &mut dw_out_buf_len as *mut u32);

            if dw_ret_val != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.0 {
                panic!();
            }

            println!("Size: {}", dw_out_buf_len);
            // allocate that amount of memory, which will be used as a buffer
            let mut ip_interface_info = Vec::with_capacity(dw_out_buf_len as usize);
            let mut ptr = ip_interface_info.as_mut_ptr() as *mut IP_INTERFACE_INFO;

            dw_ret_val = GetInterfaceInfo(ptr, &mut dw_out_buf_len as *mut u32);

            println!("Num adapters: {}", (*ptr).NumAdapters);
            for i in 0..(*ptr).NumAdapters as usize {
                println!(
                    "\tAdapter index: {}\n\tAdapter name: {}",
                    (*ptr).Adapter[i].Index,
                    String::from_utf16(&(*ptr).Adapter[i].Name).unwrap()
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes when I'm trying to access the second entry (even though there *should* be two available):

```
panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 1 but the index is 1'
```

The struct [`IP_INTERFACE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-ip_interface_info) containing all data has a field called `Adapter` which seems to be limited to only be array size of 1. Am I reading this correctly? How is it then supposed to hold multiple adapters?

```
#[repr(C)]
#[doc = "*Required features: `\"Win32_NetworkManagement_IpHelper\"`*"]
pub struct IP_INTERFACE_INFO {
    pub NumAdapters: i32,
    pub Adapter: [IP_ADAPTER_INDEX_MAP; 1],
}
```

Comment: Since I'm dealing with raw pointers, I was under the impression that the length does not matter in this case. The windows rust crate does not treat it as a vector.

Setting the length with .set_len() did not make any difference.

Comment: Yes! I was using the documentation for C++ as a reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getinterfaceinfo). Just trying to allocate the amount of bytes the function says it needs. What I find odd is that the struct (IP_INTERFACE_INFO) has an array of size 1(?).

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about doing something like that, but it felt inconsistent with the documentation. I'll never know if I don't try it though! I'll give it a shot.

Ops! Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Note that this code is unsound: it may underalign `ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [`IP_INTERFACE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-ip_interface_info) uses a C [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), which often [uses the `[1]` syntax](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member). The C++ example in [Managing Interfaces Using GetInterfaceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/managing-interfaces-using-getinterfaceinfo) corroborates this usage:

```cpp
for (i = 0; i < (unsigned int) pInterfaceInfo->NumAdapters; i++) {
    printf("  Adapter Index[%d]: %ld\n", i,
           pInterfaceInfo->Adapter[i].Index);
    printf("  Adapter Name[%d]:  %ws\n\n", i,
           pInterfaceInfo->Adapter[i].Name);
}
```

The equivalent in Rust would be to take the single-element array, get the raw pointer to it, then iterate over that. There are lots of details to be aware of, such as allocation alignment and pointer provenance. Here's an annotated example:

```rust
use std::{
    alloc::{GlobalAlloc, Layout, System},
    mem,
    ptr::{self, addr_of},
    slice,
};
use windows::{
    Win32::Foundation::*,
    Win32::NetworkManagement::IpHelper::{
        GetInterfaceInfo, IP_ADAPTER_INDEX_MAP, IP_INTERFACE_INFO,
    },
};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        // Perform the first call to know how many bytes to allocate
        let mut raw_buf_len = 0;
        let ret_val = GetInterfaceInfo(ptr::null_mut(), &mut raw_buf_len);
        assert_eq!(
            ret_val, ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.0,
            "Expected to get the required buffer size, was {ret_val:?}",
        );

        // Allocate an appropriately sized *and aligned* buffer to store the result
        let buf_len = raw_buf_len.try_into().expect("Invalid buffer length");
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(buf_len, mem::align_of::<IP_INTERFACE_INFO>())
            .expect("Could not calculate the appropriate memory layout");
        let base_ptr = System.alloc(layout);
        let ip_interface_info = base_ptr.cast();

        // Perform the second call to get the data
        let ret_val = GetInterfaceInfo(ip_interface_info, &mut raw_buf_len);
        assert_eq!(
            ret_val, NO_ERROR.0,
            "Could not get the data on the second call: {ret_val:?}",
        );

        // Construct a pointer to the adapter array that preserves the provenance of the original pointer
        let adapter_ptr = addr_of!((*ip_interface_info).Adapter);
        let adapter_ptr = adapter_ptr.cast::<IP_ADAPTER_INDEX_MAP>();

        // Combine the pointer and length into a Rust slice
        let n_adapters = (*ip_interface_info).NumAdapters;
        let n_adapters = n_adapters.try_into().expect("Invalid adapter count");
        let adapters = slice::from_raw_parts(adapter_ptr, n_adapters);

        println!("Num adapters: {}", adapters.len());
        for adapter in adapters {
            let IP_ADAPTER_INDEX_MAP {
                Index: index,
                Name: name,
            } = adapter;

            // The fixed-size buffer contains data after the UTF-16 NUL character
            let name_end = name.iter().position(|&c| c == 0).unwrap_or(name.len());
            let name = String::from_utf16_lossy(&name[..name_end]);

            println!("Adapter index: {index}\nAdapter name: {name}",);
        }

        // Free the allocation. This should be wrapped in a type that
        // implements `Drop` so we don't leak memory when unwinding a panic.
        System.dealloc(base_ptr, layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick help and all the edits! I did something similar (with .offset()), and it worked (running via wine).

Comment: Just be sure that the flexible array member is actually allocated for the size you're accessing it. If you're allocating the struct yourself, you'll likely have to do something manual in order to allocate enough space.

Comment: Reflecting on the question/code, this was an issue with the bounds-checking made by Rust (since the struct states that the lenght should be '1'). Had I used indexing without bounds-checking (get_unchecked()), I wouldn't have encountered any issues.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I assume that enough bytes are allocated since the amount allocated is what was returned by the first call to "GetInterfaceInfo()", as per documentation/examples (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ipexport/ns-ipexport-ip_interface_info). The amount returned/allocated seems to include the size of all struct members.

Comment: I'm afraid this is currently UB, as you are taking a reference to a one-element array (in `as_ptr()`) and using it past its bounds. I think you need to do the arithmetic on `ptr` yourself.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks; I’ll have to take a look tomorrow when I can get to a compiler on a Windows machine. I don’t suppose you have a link to anything from the UCG group about this topic that I can read further?

Comment: [Storing an object as &Header, but reading the data past the end of the header](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/256); [Stacked Borrows: raw pointer usable only for T too strict?](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/134).

Comment: Verified that this triggers Miri (without the Win32 functions of course, I replaced them with zero-filled buffer).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman how does [this look](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=71ff28e1207abb37d1d9226fdc03a713)?

Comment: This is fine. I calculated the offset using `Layout`, but this also works. Even `addr_of!()` alone (without `offset()`) may be good; Miri doesn't report it but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thanks; I've updated. I also liked the version with just `addr_of`.

Comment: @Mah please make sure you see the new (larger!) example.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you, this was very insightfull for me! Semantics aside, would it be ok to use a vector [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04334808af3f9ef0b5c89144f3572a4c) for memory allocation instead, to avoid having to free it manually? In the future I will most likely not use a vector, but sometimes it is nice to have automatic deallocation.

Comment: @Mah no, because that `Vec<u8>` will not guarantee that the allocated memory is properly aligned to store `IP_INTERFACE_INFO` and its children.